# python django bokeh need to select picture from database instead of path

Tags: python, django, image, stream, bokeh

```
source_glyph = AjaxDataSource(
            data_url=url_pic,
            polling_interval=STREAMING_INTERVAL,
            adapter=adapter_picture,
            method="GET"
        )
        source_glyph.data = dict(
            url=[picture_path],
            x1=[int(picture_x_position)],
            y1=[int(picture_y_position)],
            w1=[int(width)],
            h1=[int(height)],
        )
        image1 = ImageURL(
            url="url",
            x="x1",
            y="y1",
            w="w1",
            h="h1",
            anchor="center",
            global_alpha=0.3
        )

        p1.add_glyph(source_glyph, image1)
```

picture path contains `f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/{only_files[0]}'`

I need to read picture from database some how instead of from a folder.
How to do it